# getting file names in R

Tags: r, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to get all the file names that are placed in Hadoop HDFS. all i find is bash command for listing files

```
hadoop fs -ls
```

is there any way to get them in R. Please guide me
Thanks!

Comment: what about `system('hadoop fs -ls')`?

Comment: `system("hadoop fs -ls",intern=T)` is not working, Error is command ls not recognized

Comment: is there anyway i may use rhipe? as i installed Rhipe instead of RHDFS??

Comment: i used Rhipe's command rhlist("/") and it returned data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used Rhipe's command `rhlist("/")` and it returned data frame.

Answer (score 2):

```
setpw("/directory/of/choice")
list.files()
```

The result is a character vector of file names in the Present Working directory

But it occurs to me that hadoop is special. So maybe this works in your situation

```
system("hadoop fs -ls", intern=T)
```

The result is again a character vector of file names, assuming "hadoop fs -ls" actually returns something similar to "ls" in a system console.

Comment: `system("hadoop fs -ls",intern=T)` is not working, Error is command ls not recognized

Comment: it could be that you need to specify the full path to the hadoop command. e.g. "/usr/bin/hadoop fs -ls" or "/home/username/hadoop/hadoop fs -ls" or something similar.

Comment: @SaghirA.Khatri It looks like the second answer is more specific to your problem, whereas mine is much more general and depends on a system command that I have never used. See the link in the next answer. The rhdfs package contains a hdfs.list.files() and hdfs.ls() functions.

Comment: yeah i am looking on RHDFS

Comment: is there anyway i may use rhipe? as i installed Rhipe instead of RHDFS??

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [RHadoop project](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki). In particular the package you need to list files is rhdfs.

Comment: is there anyway i may use rhipe? as i installed Rhipe instead of RHDFS??

Answer (score 1):

Thought people might find this answer useful, here is the code to get files names from a specific hdfs folder into R using rhdfs.

R Code:

```
# Load required library and set hadoop environment
library(rhdfs)
Sys.setenv("HADOOP_CMD"="/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/bin/hadoop")

# Initialise
hdfs.init()

# Extract files names from a given hdfs folder to a data frame
files <- as.data.frame(hdfs.ls('/'))
```

Output:

```
> files #Print data frame

  permission   owner      group   size          modtime          file
1 -rw-r--r-- manohar supergroup 204632 2015-01-13 22:45 /LICENSES.txt
2 drwxr-xr-x manohar supergroup      0 2014-12-20 19:51           /SA
3 drwxr-xr-x manohar supergroup      0 2015-01-10 18:16           /in
```